# Installing and using anaconda on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, python, anaconda

I am trying to install and use anaconda on Ubuntu Desktop (19.04) by following the instructions [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) but I'm having trouble in step 11. When I try to run the command `conda init` or `conda config --set auto_activate_base False` I get

```
ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`
or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using conda as an application.
If your intention is to install conda as a standalone application, currently
supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda
installer.  You can download the miniconda installer from
https://conda.io/miniconda.html.
```

even though I did not use pip or easy install to install (I followed all the previous instructions in the page I linked to)

PS: I'm not using virtualization

Comment: @K7AAY I added the info you proposed